# Como pegar o index do botão clicado?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou usando um loop para gerar elementos dinamicamente:

```
for(var i =0; i< arrSequencia.length;i++ ){
strInterface += "<tr class='formulario'>"+
    "<td class='col-md-1'>"+
        "   <input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-info-bloco sembloco\" value=\"Botao "+arrSequencia[i]+"\"/>"+
        "</td>"+

    "</tr>";
}
```

Tem como eu capturar o index do botão clicado ?
Por exemplo:

**Problema:**

Se eu clicar no segundo botão, é me retornado o index: **1**

```
    var acaoBotao = function() {
        //PEGAR O INDEX
    };

    function adicionaOuRemove() {
        var botoes = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-info-bloco");
        for(var i=0;i<botoes.length;i++){
            botoes[i].addEventListener('click', acaoBotao, false);
        }
    }
```

Exemplo:

```js
var arrSequencia = [1,2,3,4,5];
var strInterface ="";

$(document).ready(function(){menuQuestoes = $("#table");

for(var i =0; i< arrSequencia.length;i++ ){
    strInterface += "<tr class='formulario'>"+
                "<td class='col-md-1'>"+
                "   <input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-info-bloco sembloco\" value=\"Botao "+arrSequencia[i]+"\"/>"+
                "</td>"+

                "</tr>";
}
        menuQuestoes.find("#tbody-content").append(strInterface);

                            
});

var acaoBotao = function() {
    
alert("//PEGAR O INDEX");
};

function adicionaOuRemove() {
    var botoes = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-info-bloco");
    for(var i=0;i<botoes.length;i++){
        botoes[i].addEventListener('click', acaoBotao, false);
    }
}
adicionaOuRemove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody id="tbody-content"></tbody>
</table>
```

No [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbdnew6g/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma vez que já tens um loop para criar os botões podes usar isso mesmo e inserir o index num campo `data-index`. Nesse caso o código seria assim:

```
for(var i =0; i< arrSequencia.length;i++ ){
    strInterface += "<tr class='formulario'>"+
                "<td class='col-md-1'>"+
                "   <input type=\"button\" data-index=\"" + i + "\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-info-bloco sembloco\" value=\"Botao "+arrSequencia[i]+"\"/>"+
                "</td>"+

                "</tr>";
}
```

e depois dentro da tua função `acaoBotao` podes fazer:

```
 var index = this.dataset.index;
```

Outra alternativa é fazer isso quando juntas os observadores de eventos. Nesse caso poderias fazer assim:

```
var acaoBotao = function (index) {
    return function(){
     // usar o index   
    }
};

function adicionaOuRemove() {
    var botoes = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-info-bloco");
    for (var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
        botoes[i].addEventListener('click', acaoBotao(i), false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
   alert(($this).val());
});
```

Use o `this` para isso. Na função do click você tem que colocar o seletor como classe do botão, visto que serão vários. No seu caso tem várias classes o botão, mas eu coloquei a `.btn`.

JS

```
var acaoBotao = function() {
    alert(this.value);
};
```

Comment: há um jeito de pegar o index sem ser pelo value? tentei passar o i para a função          botoes[i].addEventListener('click', acaoBotao(i), false);
, mas não deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Como cada botão está em uma linha distinta da sua tabela, você pode "simular" o índice dele adicionando um atributo no seu botão quando cria ele, e depois recuperar este índice utilizando a função [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) do jQuery. Exemplo:

```
for(var i =0; i< arrSequencia.length;i++ ){
strInterface += "<tr class='formulario'>"+
    "<td class='col-md-1'>"+
        "   <input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-info-bloco sembloco\" value=\"Botao "+arrSequencia[i]+"\" data-index=\" + i +\"/>"+
        "</td>"+

    "</tr>";
}

var acaoBotao = function(el) {
    return $(el.srcElement).data('index');
};
```

Exemplo no [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/43n6kgwv/)